# Save in ReactiveCrudRepository not inserting or updating records

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, reactive-programming, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

As stated in the title I'm not been able to insert or update records in my Postgres database.
I just started working with spring and kotlin so there might be some pretty basic configuration that it's missing. Thanks in advance

Here is my code base

**UserRepository**

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository : ReactiveCrudRepository<User, Int> {}
```

**User model**
@Table("user_app")

```
data class User (
    @Id
    @Column("id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id : Int? =  null,

    @Column("username")
    val username : String?,

    @Column("email")
    val email : String?,

    @Column("name")
    val name : String?,

    @Column("password")
    val password : String?
)
```

**UserController**
@Component

```
class UserController{

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var userRepository : UserRepository

    fun getAllUsers() : Flux<User> = userRepository.findAll()

    fun getUserById( userId: Int) : Mono<User> = userRepository.findById(userId)

    fun createUser(user: User): Mono<User> = userRepository.save(user)

    fun updateUser(user: User) : Mono<User> = userRepository.save(user)

}
```

**UserConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
class UserConfiguration {

    @FlowPreview
    @Bean
    fun userRouter(controller: UserController): RouterFunction<ServerResponse> = router{
        ("/users").nest{
            GET("") { _ ->
                ServerResponse.ok().body(controller.getAllUsers())
            }

            GET("/{id}") { req ->
                ServerResponse.ok().body(controller.getUserById(req.pathVariable("id").toInt()))
            }

            accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            POST("") {req ->
                ServerResponse.ok().body(req.bodyToMono(User::class.java).doOnNext { user ->
                        controller.createUser(user)                })
            }

            accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            PUT("") {req ->
                ServerResponse.ok().body(req.bodyToMono(User::class.java).doOnNext { user ->
                    run {
                        controller.updateUser(user)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**R2dbcConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableR2dbcRepositories
class R2dbcConfiguration  : AbstractR2dbcConfiguration() {
    @Bean
    override fun connectionFactory(): PostgresqlConnectionFactory  {
        val config = PostgresqlConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .host("localhost")
                .port(5432)
                .database("postgres")
                .username("postgres")
                .password("pass123")
                .build()

        return PostgresqlConnectionFactory(config)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found out why this wasnt working.
Save does not persist the changes in the database, to do that you need to call some methods. I called subscribe but because this is a blocking method I ran it either in a let block or a doOnNext

```
fun createUser(request: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
        println("createUser")
        val badRequest = ServerResponse.badRequest().build()
        val user = request.bodyToMono(User::class.java)

        return user
                .doOnNext { u -> userRepository.save(u).subscribe() }
                .flatMap {
                    ServerResponse.ok().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).body(fromValue(it))
                }
    }
```